# Php setcookie() doesnt work

Tags: php, oop, cookies, set

as the title says I have a problem with setcookie() function - it simply doesn't work. I'd really appreciate if you could point out where I made a mistake. I am trying to create a simple login script:

index.php:

```
<?php

include_once("mysql.php");
include_once("security.php");
global $connection;

    if (isset($_POST['name']) and isset($_POST['pass'])) {

        if($Action -> login($_POST['name'],$_POST['pass']) == true){

            $Security -> create_cookie($_POST['name']);
            echo "Login successful!";
        }
        elseif($Action -> login($_POST['name'],$_POST['pass']) == false){
            echo "Login failed! Given information was incorrect.";
        }
    }
    else{
        include_once("layout/login.php");
    }
?>
```

mysql.php:

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db_name = "game";
global $connection;
$connection = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db_name);

if($connection->connect_errno) echo "Connection to the database failed:". $connection->connect_errno.".";?>
```

layout/login.php:

```
<?php

echo "<form name =\"login\" method = \"post\" action=\"\" style=\"border: 1px;\">
Name:</br>
<input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" length=\"28\"><br/>
Password:</br>
<input type=\"password\" name=\"pass\"></br></br>
<input type=\"submit\" name=\"button\" value=\"Login\"/>
</form>
";
?>
```

and security.php:

```
    <?php


class Security{



function create_cookie($user){
    global $connection;

    //cookie settings
    $name    = "login_script";
    $value   = md5(md5(md5(time()).md5("65ds4fg6s1df56g165sdf"))."5sdfg5462gs1df6g8518s");
    $time    = time()+3600*24*14;
    $path    = "/";
    $domain  = "localhost";
    $sec     = 0;

    $connection -> query("UPDATE users SET session = '$value' WHERE user = '$user' LIMIT 1");

    return setcookie($name,$value,$time,$path,$domain,$sec);
}   


function encrypt($phrase){

    $salt = "d6f5g4e2rnwber21";
    $extra_salt = "2n1k";
    $pass = md5(md5($phrase).md5($salt)).$extra_salt;
    return $pass;       
}



}

class Action extends Security{

function login($urn, $pass){
    global $connection;
    $query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT password FROM users WHERE user = '$urn' LIMIT 1");
    $result = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
    if($result[0] == $this->encrypt($pass)){    
        return true;
    }
    elseif($result[0] != $this->encrypt($pass)){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        $error = mysqli_error();
        $errno = mysqli_errno();
        $report = "Unknown error occured: no. ".$errno.". Error: ".$error.".";
        return $report;
    }
}



$Security = new Security();
$Action = new Action();
?>
```

With LiveHTTPHeader addon I got:

```html
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: lt,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,ru;q=0.4,pl;q=0.2
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 17
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Sat, 08 Aug 2015 08:03:23 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12
Set-Cookie: login_script=37fd88cddf9a75f8b758ba1a62317215; expires=Sat, 22-Aug-2015 08:03:23 GMT; Max-Age=1209600; path=/; domain=localhost
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.12
```

### So from the last part of the header it seems that the browser should create a cookie. But it doesn't. Have been googling and experimenting for past 2 hours, can't figure out where the problem lies. Also if you see something stupid or archaic, feel free to throw in an extra advice. Thank you.

Ok, problem solved. Turns out Chrome doesn't allow to set cookies on localhost (127.0.0.1 also doesn't seem to work). However if you leave domain parameter empty chrome automatically takes the current website (even if it's a localhost) as a domain for the cookie. I hope this will save tons of time for someone. And my thanks to those who helped me.

Comment: What's the code checking for the cookie's existence ?

Comment: global should be used within a function, not inline with other script. The encrypt function uses md5 which should be considered broken and not much use for passwords - it is a hashing function rather than encryption. You can't generally set a cookie if anything has been output to the browser before the call to setcookie().

Comment: @Spenidus I am checking for cookie's existence manually - in browser's settings.

Comment: @RamRaider yah, I've read about that while trying to solve this with google's help. But it seems that setcookie() is first. Can't think of anything else.

Comment: The output from liveheaders looks like the cookie is being set- does print_r($_COOKIE) not show anything after the page has loaded?

Comment: Just tried it - nothing. :(

Comment: I tried your code and it worked for me!

Comment: I hate my life :( So the problem might be my php settings, or the browser, right..?

Comment: Beside the point of cookies.. why are you using md5?

Comment: Probably the browser considering the http response contains the cookie header. Or maybe some sort of discrepancy, like setting "localhost" but not accessing from localhost.

Comment: @Daryl Gill Well, it was the first thing that came to my mind when I saw plane password in the database. Also I am learning from a book called "PHP, MYSQL and Apache 2007" , so I guess it's a little outdated. Could you tell me what I should be using instead of md5?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

Comment: Thank you. Well, I've downloaded Mozilla, there my script actually works. Not sure what's wrong with Chrome and IE(well I am pretty sure what's wrong with this one). Going to double check Chrome's settings again. Thank you guys, I appreciate your help. :)

Comment: @user2964516 You can post an answer to your own question to help other people that might come here.

Comment: Why don't you use sessions?